# DB::reconnect() in Schema Facade?

Tags: database, laravel

I am working on a multiple database system. System will integrate clients local mssql server.

I will store credential info in my master database. And i want to migrate some tables to my customers local database.

As you know we can choose connection as below.

```
Schema::connection('sqlsrv')->create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {

});
```

But I have to use it dynamically.

This connection reads from config/database.php

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('SQLSRV_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('SQLSRV_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('SQLSRV_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('SQLSRV_PASSWORD', ''),
        'collation' => 'Turkish_CI_AS',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => env('SQLSRV_PREFIX', ''),
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
    ],

],
```

I did it in using DB Facade.

```
public function getConnection($connection_id)
{
    /** Bağlantı Bilgilerini Çeker */
    $connection = Connection::find($connection_id);

    try
    {
        /** Bağlantı Ayarları */
        config()->set('database.connections.sqlsrv.host', $connection->host);
        config()->set('database.connections.sqlsrv.database',  $connection->db);
        config()->set('database.connections.sqlsrv.username',  $connection->username);
        config()->set('database.connections.sqlsrv.password',  $connection->password);
        config()->set('database.connections.sqlsrv.charset',  $connection->charset);
        config()->set('database.connections.sqlsrv.collation',  $connection->collation);
        config()->set('database.connections.sqlsrv.prefix',  $connection->prefix);

        /** Ayarlar ile yeniden bağlanma */
        return DB::reconnect($connection->driver);
    }catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        throw new \Exception($e);
    }
}
```

Is there any method or solution like DB::reconnect() in Schema Facade ?

Comment: Currently looking for something like this. Did you find any solution for Schema?

Comment: no i haven't find a solution yet

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up doing. Hope it helps your case.

```
    // Erase the tenant connection, thus making Laravel
    // get the default values all over again.
    DB::purge('tenant');

    // Make sure to use the database name we want to establish a connection.
    Config::set('database.connections.tenant.host', $company->database->main_server);
    Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $company->mysql_database);
    Config::set('database.connections.tenant.username', $company->mysql_username);
    Config::set('database.connections.tenant.password', $company->mysql_password);

    // Rearrange the connection data
    DB::reconnect('tenant');

    // Ping the database. This will thrown an exception in case
    // the database does not exists.
    Schema::connection('tenant')->getConnection()->reconnect();
```

I noticed that if you do not `DB::purge`, Schema will not be able to pick up any connection change.

On the other hand, if you do purge, but the database doesn't exist, you won't get an exception until you actually try to do something with the database connection. The `reconnect()` in the last line will trigger that.

Comment: You saved my hours. Hats Off.  Most of the answers don't use DB:purge('db_connection'). It is the best advice to use Purge before reconnect